# Game based on real historical events

Tags: game

I am looking for a game for a friend that is based on real history. It can be a  PC (Windows), online (webapp), or an Android game. It doesn't matter if it is RPG, strategy, or adventure.

Here are a few examples:

- **Age of Empires** (all of them). They are based on different Nations histories and how they have evolved through the years.
- **Total War**. Same as above.
- **Valiant Hearts: The Great War**. Adventure, puzzle game related to the World War I.
- **Crusader kings 2**. Medival history.
- **Kings of Honor**. Same as above.

If it is a PC or online game, the system requirements are not being a problem. However, if it is an Android game, the smartphone is two years old with Dual Core CPU and 3" display. So, I wouldn't opt for any high-tech game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many!

For RTS you can use the list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_real-time_strategy_video_games , sort by "Setting", then for each game with historical setting check whether it's based on fictional or real history.

Answer (score 4):

Looking through my steam, Origin and UPlay libraries:

The Assassin's Creed series, while a romanticized and somewhat alternative version of history, has a huge number of references to actual events from the crusades, Early renaissance Europe, Colonial America and mid-1700s Carribean. It shows a lot of events that actually happened, usually even in the same way as they happened.

Europa Universalis IV is an in-depth turn-based game set in medieval times, with great historical accuracy.

Another good place to look is the Historical tag on Steam: http://store.steampowered.com/search/?tags=3987#sort_by=Name_ASC&tags=3987&page=1 There are currently 111 games with this tag on Steam.

Answer (score 3):

I've played a couple of games that were based on historical events

- **Empire Earth**: based on the progress of civilization; from cave men to the information age, passing through the sailing days, World War I, and World War II
- **Call of Duty**, **Call of Duty 2**, and **Call of Duty: World at War**: All based on World War II

All of these games are PC games